# XSLT: Combining two XML elements into one output element with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

and this will be my first post.
I want to create a XSLT file for 2 XML file. I dont know where to begin with.

This is the students XML files:

```
<students>
  <student id="a01" list="c001,c002,c004">
     <first>Beverly</first>
     <last>Kaufmann</last>
  </student>
  <student id="a02" list="c003,c005, c006">
     <first>Kevin</first>
     <last>Yates</last>
  </student>
```

This is the students XML files:

```
 <contributions>
  <contributor id="c001" student="a01">
     <first>David</first>
     <last>Lee</last>
     <address>
        <street>212 West Advent St.</street>
        <city>Cutler</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>32815</zip>
        <phone>555-7812</phone>
     </address>
     <amount>$150</amount>
  </contributor>
  <contributor id="c002" student="a01">
     <first>Karen</first>
     <last>Belaska</last>
     <address>
        <street>500 Maple Ln.</street>
        <city>Cutler</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>32817</zip>
        <phone>555-3219</phone>
     </address>
     <amount>$50</amount>
  </contributor>
  <contributor id="c003" student="a02">
     <first>Alice</first>
     <last>Sanchez</last>
     <address>
        <street>5 North St.</street>
        <city>Davidton</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>39810</zip>
        <phone>555-0190</phone>
     </address>
     <amount>$225</amount>
  </contributor>
  <contributor id="c004" student="a01">
     <first>Allen</first>
     <last>Chmurutra</last>
     <address>
        <street>400 Main St.</street>
        <city>Davidton</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>39112</zip>
        <phone>555-4388</phone>
     </address>
     <amount>$125</amount>
  </contributor>
  <contributor id="c005" student="a02">
     <first>Cynthia</first>
     <last>Whyte</last>
     <address>
        <street>657 Hemisphere Dr.</street>
        <city>Cutler</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>31287</zip>
        <phone>555-0923</phone>
     </address>
     <amount>$50</amount>
  </contributor>
  <contributor id="c006" student="a02">
     <first>Alison</first>
     <last>Heart</last>
     <address>
        <street>622 Hemisphere Dr.</street>
        <city>Cutler</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>31287</zip>
        <phone>555-0923</phone>
     </address>
     <amount>$100</amount>
  </contributor>
```

I wanted to create table for these to xml file. something like this:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOf6Z.jpg)
I dont know where to begin with. please help!

Comment: Please post the expected output **as code** within your question. Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Please post your XSLT as far as you got and the desired outcome.

Comment: We hope those are NOT actual names and addresses. If so, please **scrub** data as those folks may not appreciate this!

Comment: This seems to be some kind of homework. Google the names and some exercise pages will turn up.

Comment: Thanks guys !! I figured out a solution on xslt already. I want to post here too. but somehow when i copy and paste the code into stackoverflow, it couldnt display all of my code. Anyone knows whats is wrong here???